# Using posix semphores question

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I am curios if i implement this correct using semaphores.I want that clientThread to execute only after serverThread finish.
My current code gives me an error(not compile/linker error) with "Close program"(only if i print in clientThread) Here is my code:

```
void* serverThread(void* sock)
{
    sem_wait(&mutex);
    Handle handle((TCPSocket*)sock);
    handle.HandleAuthentication();
    sem_post(&mutex);
    sem_post(&mutex2);
}

void* clientThread(void* sock)
{
    sem_wait(&mutex2);
    cout << "Address is: -> " << Handle::getAddress() << " ------ " << Handle::getPort() << endl;
    sem_post(&mutex2);
}

int main()
{
    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&mutex2, 0, 0);
    unsigned short echoServPort = 9898;

    try {
        TCPServerSocket servSock(echoServPort);

        for (;;) {  
            TCPSocket* sock = servSock.accept();
            pthread_t pidClient, pidServer;
            if(pthread_create(&pidServer, NULL, serverThread, (void*)sock) != 0)
            {
                throw SocketException("Unable to create server thread (pthread_create()", true);
            }
            if(pthread_create(&pidClient, NULL, clientThread, NULL) != 0)
            {
                throw SocketException("Unable to create client thread (pthread_create()", true);
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException &e) {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

edit:
This are the errors after inspecting with gdb:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x6fcb6afb in libstdc++-6!_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES
5_PKc () from c:\MinGW\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
#1  0x0040146d in _fu0___ZSt4cout (sock=0x0) at ..\src\client.cpp:212
#2  0x6e0c5121 in ptw32_threadStart@4 () from c:\MinGW\bin\libpthread-2.dll
#3  0x76e01287 in msvcrt!_itow_s () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#4  0x76e01328 in msvcrt!_endthreadex () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#5  0x76cb1174 in KERNEL32!AcquireSRWLockExclusive ()
   from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
#6  0x76efb3f5 in ntdll!RtlInsertElementGenericTableAvl ()
   from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#7  0x76efb3c8 in ntdll!RtlInsertElementGenericTableAvl ()
   from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#8  0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a loop in your code so you probably meant something like:

```
void* serverThread(void* sock)
{
    sem_wait(&empty);
    Handle handle((TCPSocket*)sock);
    handle.HandleAuthentication();
    sem_post(&full);
}

void* clientThread(void* sock)
{
    sem_wait(&full);
    cout << "Address is: -> " << Handle::getAddress() << " ------ " << Handle::getPort() << endl;
    sem_post(&empty);
}

int main()
{
    sem_init(&full, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&empty, 0, 1);
    ...
```

If you program crashes then it would be better to compile it with `-O0 -g` and run under `gdb` to inspect the stack trace.

Or you can do `ulimit -c unlimited` in a shell so that core file will be created automatically.

Comment: yes,yor code is better,thanx , now i still need to find out why it crashes

Comment: @vBx just run with `gdb ./your_app`. In gdb enter `r` to run the program. And enter `bt` (backtrace) after it crashes.

Comment: i did it,but to be true i dont understand nothing...:(

Comment: i put the output in my original post

Comment: @vBx Yep, names are mangled, not very convenient. Important line: `#1  0x0040146d in _fu0___ZSt4cout (sock=0x0) at ..\src\client.cpp:212` It looks like that you've passed a NULL `sock` pointer in client.cpp on line 212. That's why the program has crashed.

Comment: i knew that line cause problems,if i comment that it works. Its the cout inside clientThread,and the sock NULL pointer is the argument of the function,that it supossed to be void*. I am confuse,cause i dont use that argument

Comment: @vBx Then probably `sock=0x0` just indicates the value of a local variable. What do Handle::getAddress() and Handle::getPort() return? Do they return references to objects created inside the functions?

Comment: they return static data: a static char* and a static short

Comment: @vBx Probably you initialize that static char * with a temporary variable inside `HandleAuthentication()` or something like that. So it holds an invalid pointer. You can use static std::string instead.

Comment: well,yes,i am initializing the static data outside the class: char* Handle::destinationAddress = "";
short Handle::port = 0; and yes the problem is with the destinationAddress,because if i print only handle::getPort() the program crashes,but i dont know,how to initialize it then ?

Comment: everytime the data is empty when returning,strange

Comment: @vBx Please let me see your Handle class too.

Comment: @vBx I can' understand how you assign `Handle::destinationAddress` now. Anyway you probably assign a pointer to some kind of temporary string.